# Ruby on Rails - How to list items from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a topics table where I have some topics that I want to list but all I can get it's their IDs and not the topic name.

On my migrations file I have:

```
class CreateTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :topics do |t|
      t.string :topic
      t.integer :sort  # for RailsSortable

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And on the TopicsController:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @topics = Topic.order(:sort)
    end

    def topic
        @topics = Topic.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end
end
```

The topic Model looks like this:

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord

    include RailsSortable::Model
    set_sortable :sort  # Indicate a sort column

end
```

And on the .erb I have this:

```
  <% @topics = Topic.all %>
  <%= @topics.ids %>
```

and **the output is [1,2]** which is good because the table only hast 2 rows.
But what I needed was to display a (sortable) table list.

I tried this:

```
  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <tr id="<%= topic.sortable_id %>">
  <% end %>
```

but it doesn't return anything. What am I missing here?

**SOLVED**

Ok, the problem was topic.topic was returning nil, but if I add <% @topics = Topic.all %> before the loop it knows there is a topic there.

```
  <% @topics = Topic.all %>

  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= topic.topic %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML. And, you're not outputting anything except a `tr` element (with no closing element) with an `id` equal to `topic.sortable_id` (is that even a field?). So, naturally you're not going see anything on your page. Also, in your `TopicsController`, I don't know what you're planning on doing with that `topic` action. Is that supposed to be a `show` action?

Comment: this is the gem I'm trying to use: https://github.com/itmammoth/rails_sortable. topic.sortable_id is the same as topic.sort (which is my table field, but the field I need is topic, but topic.topic returns nill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this in your view.

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>TOPIC</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= topic.id %></td>
      <td><%= topic.topic %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: if I use topic.topic it returns nil for some reason... but yes, I'm trying to get the topic

Comment: This helped, but I needed to add   <% @topics = Topic.all %> above the table or else it returned nil topics.

Comment: `@topics = Topic.all.order(:sort)` add this to you index action and try, please avoid calling model value inside the views.

Comment: if topic.topic returns nil value sometime its because you have some topic in which the topic is empty string or value less. you can avoid that with a condition inside a tr tag

Comment: I understand what you're saying about not calling model values inside the view, but it's not working otherwise. I tried @topics = Topic.all.order(:sort) inside my TopicsController and removed it from the view, but then I got a nill (and the table has elements). If I place it on the view, everything turns out ok... weird

Comment: the view is called "_core_form.html.erb". It's my user settings page.

Comment: add this `@topics = Topic.all` in your corresponding controller action